# brew install cpp-ethereum CMake Error

Tags: cmake, ethereum

I am trying to manually build my ethereum client on Mac OS X 10.13.5 (using brew gives me a similar error).  I follow the simple instructions to :

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum.git
cd cpp-ethereum
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
```

It gives me an error and fails the build:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    evmc/cmake/cable/bootstrap.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    CableBuildInfo


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    CableBuildType


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    CableToolchains


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (cable_configure_toolchain):
  Unknown CMake command "cable_configure_toolchain".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I know CMake is used to manage the building process but Id on't understand what is causing the problem. What is this CMakeList that is causing my build to fail and how do I troubleshoot these?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum/blob/develop/README.md) carefully: it tells about `git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum.git`, and notes that `--recursive` option is important.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum.git
```

I read it from the aleth github project.

Answer (score 1):

Run this inside the cloned folder

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```